# epigraph environment messes up subsequent text

Tags: epigraphs

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{epigraph}
    \setlength\epigraphwidth{0.93\textwidth}
    \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Consequently, under application of the aforementioned criterion of physical reality:
\epigraph{(I) Only one of the corresponding properties can be 'real' at any time.}
Subsequently, the focus is shifted onto an entangled state of two particles that have seized to interact and are far removed from another.

\end{document}
```

produces the following output:
[image]
Amending the code by `\noindent`, i.e.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{epigraph}
    \setlength\epigraphwidth{0.93\textwidth}
    \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Consequently, under application of the aforementioned criterion of physical reality:
\epigraph{(I) Only one of the corresponding properties can be 'real' at any time.}
\noindent Subsequently, the focus is shifted onto an entangled state of two particles that have seized to interact and are far removed from another.

\end{document}
```

improves the output to:
[image]
A) Why is this necessary and B) How can I get rid of the remaining indentation on the paragraph starting with "Subsequently"?

Comment: I'm afraid  you're confusing an epigraph and a cross-reference or a quote. An epigraph is not designed to be found mid document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `epigraph` package was never designed for putting an epigraph in the middle of a paragraph. An epigraph essentially forms its own kind of displayed "paragraph".

I have modified your MWE to show how `\paragraph` is normally used.

```
% epigraphprob.tex SE 546919

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{epigraph}
    \setlength\epigraphwidth{0.93\textwidth}
    \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\epigraphnoindent

\begin{document}

Consequently, under application of the aforementioned criterion of 
physical reality:

\chapter{One}
\epigraph{(I) Only one of the corresponding properties can be 'real' 
at any time.}{}

Subsequently, the focus is shifted onto an entangled state of two particles 
that have seized to interact and are far removed from another.

\end{document}
```

Two comments: the `\epigraphnoindent` in the preamble stops the indentation of text that follows a paragraph that follows a divisional heading (`\chapter` in the above); `\paragraph` takes two argument, namely the text and the source --- you provided only the text.

I think that you would be better off using something like the `quote` environment.